# stopping times (definition)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stopping-times

I have the following question. If we want to verify that a random variable $T$ is a stopping time, according to the definition of a stopping time we have to show that $[T\le n]\in F_{n} $ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$. I noticed that is enough to show only $[T= n]\in F_{n}$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Why is it enought?

Answer (score 1):

It's enough because, $[T\leq n] = \cup_{k=1}^{n}[T=k]$ where $[T=k]\in\mathcal{F}_n\subset \mathcal{F}_n$ for all $1\leq k\leq n.$

Comment: So if we have stopping times $S,T$ with respect to the filtration $(F_{n}),n\in\mathbb{N}$ and we want to show that $S+T$ is a stopping time we can write $$[S+T\le n]=\cup_{j=1}^{n}[S+T=j] =\cup_{j=1}^{n}\cup_{k=1}^{n-1} [S=k]\cap [T=j-k] $$? Is it correct?

Comment: Yeah sure you can write that!

Comment: However, it is not very elegant. I guess it is better to write $[S+T\le n]=\cup_{j=1}^{n-1}([S=j]\cap [T\le n-j])$? I am just not sure if $j$ goes from $0$ or $1$? In other words if $S$ can be $0$ if we consider filtration $F_{n},n\in\mathbb{N}$?

Answer (score 0):

It is assumed that $\mathcal F_n$'s are increasing. $[T=n]=[T=1] \cup [T=2]\cup...\cup[T=n]$ and $[T=i] \in F_i \subseteq F_n$ for each $i \in \{1,2...,n\}$. Hence $[T=n] \in F_n$